# How to display Django time in 12 hour time instead of military 24

Tags: django, time

When I use the following

```
created = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

it displays time like this

```
23:12:06
```

instead of

```
11:12:06
```

I want it to display time in 12 hr not 24. Also when I press the now widget the time is 4 minutes behind. Any help would be appreciatecd

Comment: When you say display, are you talking about admin interface? Your own template? Take a look at django settings config: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#datetime-format

Comment: @ShangWang in the admin interface

Answer (score 3):

You can change input format for time field as follow:

```
created = TimeField(widget=TimeInput(format='%I:%M:%S'))
```

or

```
created = TimeField(input_formats=('%I:%M:%S'))
```

**The %I indicates a 12 hour clock format whereas the %H indicates a 24 hour clock format.**

in django we have some defined formats

**time**

```
'%H:%M:%S',     # '14:30:59'
'%H:%M:%S.%f',  # '14:30:59.000200'
'%H:%M',        # '14:30'
```

**date**

```
'%Y-%m-%d', '%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y', # '2006-10-25', '10/25/2006', '10/25/06'
'%b %d %Y', '%b %d, %Y',            # 'Oct 25 2006', 'Oct 25, 2006'
'%d %b %Y', '%d %b, %Y',            # '25 Oct 2006', '25 Oct, 2006'
'%B %d %Y', '%B %d, %Y',            # 'October 25 2006', 'October 25, 2006'
'%d %B %Y', '%d %B, %Y',            # '25 October 2006', '25 October, 2006'
```

**datetime**

```
'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',     # '2006-10-25 14:30:59'
'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f',  # '2006-10-25 14:30:59.000200'
'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',        # '2006-10-25 14:30'
'%Y-%m-%d',              # '2006-10-25'
'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',     # '10/25/2006 14:30:59'
'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f',  # '10/25/2006 14:30:59.000200'
'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',        # '10/25/2006 14:30'
'%m/%d/%Y',              # '10/25/2006'
'%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S',     # '10/25/06 14:30:59'
'%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f',  # '10/25/06 14:30:59.000200'
'%m/%d/%y %H:%M',        # '10/25/06 14:30'
'%m/%d/%y',              # '10/25/06'
```

you can use these formats to customize your fields

also see [official doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-TIME_INPUT_FORMATS)

Answer (score 1):

Django have built-in date formatting, like this:

`created = DateTimeField(input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p'])`

Here is the full cheat-sheet about how this letters work:
http://blog.tkbe.org/archive/date-filter-cheat-sheet/

So, to implement 12hour format, use 'h' or 'g' depending on if you want to have leading zeros or not

It is also mentioned in django doc:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#datetimefield

This is for dev version, i dont know which one you are using

> time is 4 minutes behind

Is your TIME_ZONE in settings correct ?

Comment: it's TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'

Answer (score 0):

add `TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%I:%M %p',)` to

> settings.py