# Django Admin DateTimeField Showing 24hr format time

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, time-format

I tried on google but I did not found the solution. In `Django` admin side, I'm displaying *start date* and *end date* with time. But time is in `24 hr` format and I want to display it in `12 hr` format

```
class CompanyEvent(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date_start = models.DateTimeField('Start Date')
    date_end = models.DateTimeField('End Date')
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'Company Event'
        verbose_name_plural = u'Company Events'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s (%s : %s)" % (self.title, self.date_start.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'), self.date_end)
```

I also found out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34639280/how-to-display-django-time-in-12-hour-time-instead-of-military-24?rq=1) but it isn't helping me.

I am new to `python` and `django`. Please help.

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: I think it captures the default from your computer. So if you region is in 24h format, it will show it like that. Have you tried changing your region format?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a matter for django's settings, not the model:
[settings doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#time-format).

Check your `TIME_INPUT_FORMATS` in `MyProject/MySite/settings.py` and add this as necessary:

```
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = [
    '%I:%M:%S %p',  # 6:22:44 PM
    '%I:%M %p',  # 6:22 PM
    '%I %p',  # 6 PM
    '%H:%M:%S',     # '14:30:59'
    '%H:%M:%S.%f',  # '14:30:59.000200'
    '%H:%M',        # '14:30'
]
```

If the display of the time format on the changelist page is still wrong, check your `LANGUAGE_CODE` and `USE_L10N` settings.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#datetimefield) you will get to know format like 
this

```
'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

where **%H** is Hour, 24-hour format with leading zeros, to get 12-hour format replace it with **%h**

So you have to use- 
'%Y-%m-%d %h:%M:%S'

Answer (score 3):

Defaultly django displays 24 hrs format, if you want to customize you need to specify the 12 hrs format. Let me know if this works

```
class CompanyEvent(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
date_start = models.DateTimeField('Start Date')
date_end = models.DateTimeField('End Date')
notes = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = u'Company Event'
    verbose_name_plural = u'Company Events'

def __unicode__(self):
    return "%s (%s : %s)" % (self.title, self.date_start.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p'), self.date_end)
```

Comment: It working fine for listing but not in detail or edit page.

Comment: Check the image i provided , that image is of edit view there i am getting the time format in 24 hr .