# How to Change Django TimeField to 24 hour Format

Tags: python, django, html, input, django-forms

I am creating Django Form and want to use TimeField with 24-hour format.

However when I try using Django widget, I get the 12-hour format. This is my code.

```
start_time = forms.TimeField(
    label="Start Time",
    widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'type': 'time'}
    )
)
```

How to change it to 24-hour format?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48514222/django-admin-datetimefield-showing-24hr-format-time/48521723

Comment: @DS I have tried adding TIME_INPUT_FORMATS and USE_L10N but nothing happened.

Comment: It has nothing to do with django. HTML5 input type time only supports 12 hour format. Please see more details here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32609407/html-input-time-in-24-format